# C# WPF Ensure a exe that starts another process of itself will be focused

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf program (topmost, WindowStyle = None and WindowState = Maximized) which will

1. Rename the running program.exe to program-old.exe
2. Download an updated program.exe
3. Do this

```cs
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("program.exe");
     System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
```

The problem I am seeing is that the re-started new program.exe will 1) not be in front of the taskbar 2) not receive focus and detect keyboard input before I click on it.

I have tried to set keyboard focus, activate, focus the window, focus controls on the window, all without luck. What else is there to try?

Comment: Just an idea (not sure it'll work) but did you try changing the first app (the one that's being shut down) to no longer be topmost before launching the new one? Because this could be an issue of there being (very briefly) two "topmost" applications competing. Also not sure if this matters but I usually use `Application.Current.Shutdown()` for WPF.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy "program.exe" to "program_old.exe"
2. Execute "program_old.exe" & shutdown current program ("program.exe")
3. In program executed in Step 2("program_old.exe"), Download new program and overwrite existing program ("program.exe")
4. Execute downloaded program ("program.exe") & shutdown current program ("program_old.exe")

or

1. Download new program as "program_new.exe"
2. Execute "program_new.exe" and shutdown current program ("program.exe")
3. In "program_new.exe", rename "program.exe" to "program_old.exe"
4. Copy "program_new.exe" to "program.exe" (overwrite)
5. Execute "program.exe" & shutdown current program ("program_new.exe")